# FireFox SSO session used by Windows for further authentications?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, internet-explorer, authentication, single-sign-on

On our document management system we use SSO and I also configured FF for auto login. Now that I extended the DMS with a feature which should load content from the Repository via SharePoint-Module in our E-Mail Client we would need a browser independent solution (or at least for FF and IE).

If I use Internet Explorer the SSO authentication session is automatically used by Windows to authenticate against the Network Adress of the DMS and the documents are loaded into the E-Mail Client without any problems.

In FireFox this is not working because the E-Mail Client can not access the Repository. I think that FF is not passing the session to Windows or anything like this. The workaround would be to open the SharePoint-Adress of the DMS at least once in Windows Explorer and manually authenticate against it (username + password).

We would need a browser independent solution without any additional authentication prompts.

Or is this a IE-only feature from Microsoft?

Best regards and thank you very much,
Pali

Comment: Since SharePoint is a Microsoft product, it is well integrated with their IE. One quick workaround you could test is the free extension for Mozilla Firefox, IE Tab, which has an IE window running inside Firefox; see https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/ietabnet/. This might not work on all Firefox installations, particularly on Linux.